# Structs and their content

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

When I'm creating structs, and those structs contain various types of variables, uint, string etc. Should i declare the visibility and if constant on those variables like with state variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only declare the visibility/constant of state variables, struct are members and you cannot declare their visibility.

```
struct S {
    uint a;
    bytes b;
    string s;
    // uint public v;  // <--- this fails to compile
}
```

But you can instantiate a struct variable and declare visibility

```
S public x;
```